# Set size of JLabel in FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, flowlayout

I have a JPanel that uses FlowLayout. I add a number of JLabels to the JPanel, use setPreferedSize() to adjust their size and save them in a list, label_list. Everything works fine. Then I want to change their size:

```
for(JLabel c:label_list){
c.setPreferedSize(new Dimension(10,10));
}
```

And it doesn't work.

```
c.setBackground(Color.red)
```

and similar stuff works. Why can't I use setPreferedSize here?

c.setBounds(1,1,10,10) and c.setSize(10,10)
Works, but after i update the UI (resizeing the panel) every size goes back to normal.

Comment: Have you requested that the container re-layout it's contents? Try invalidate, revlidate & repaint (or combinations there of)

Comment: don't use setXXSize, ever. Some reasons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi/7229519#7229519. Instead choose a LayoutManager which supports your requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Then I want to change their size:
>
> for(JLabel c:label_list){ c.setPreferedSize(new Dimension(10,10)); }
>
> And it doesn't work.

You need to call `revalidate()` on the parent of the labels so that it reperforms layout and enforces their preferred size.

> c.setBounds(1,1,10,10) and c.setSize(10,10) Works, but after i update
>   the UI (resizeing the panel) every size goes back to normal.

Setting bounds/size/location manually conflicts with the LayoutManager of the parent container. The job of the LayoutManager is to position and size the child components.

Either set the layout to `null` and call yourself setSize-setLocation/setBounds, or use a LayoutManager (recommended) and never call setSize-setLocation/setBounds. At most, you can call setPreferred/setMaximum/setMinimum size but try to avoid this as it can causes cross L&F problems.